# How to load multiple related entities in DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have 3 related tables

1. Person entity: with two Foreign keys from Address entity (Address and Address1) and one foreign key from Owners table
2. Address Entity has one foreign key from Owners table

The person view has fields from Address entity and while tracking the concurrency check

```
var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
var databaseValues = (Person)entry.GetDatabaseValues().ToObject();
var clientValues = (Person)entry.Entity;
```

works fine for Person fields.

However when I try to access

databasevalues.Address.City or databasevalues.Address1.City it gives a null exception. This I think is due to Address Entity not loaded in the begining

Request for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You might try explicitly loading the related entities in your query:

```
IQueryable<Person> persons = DataContext.Persons.Where(p => p.City == "Hoboken").Include("Address")
```

would explicitly load related address entries for the person instances returned.

Another option is to disable the Lazy Loading option in your edmx file; open the file, then the properties panel, set Lazy Loading = false.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I try to use your query to load the person edit view it gives an exception that its not of type model person. I thought if I load address while loading the edit view the dbupdate concurrency exception will have address as well, any ideas how to send address in edit view as model, or else what else could be the solution